# Looping in SAS to bring the latest value

Tags: sas

I am trying to find days matching to a reference number of days given or else to find the number of days close to the reference days.

I coded till here, however not sure how to go forward.

```
ID Date ref_days lags total_days
1  2017-02-02 224 . 0
1  2017-02-02 224 84 84
1  2017-02-02 224 84 168
2  2015-01-21 213 300 388 
3  2016-02-12 560 95 .
3  2016-02-12 560 86 181
3  2016-02-12 560 82 263
3  2016-02-12 560 69 332
3  2016-02-12 560 77 409
```

So now I want to bring out the last value close to the reference days. 
and the next total_days should start from ZERO again to find the next window. How can I do this?

Here is a code that I wrote

```
data want; 
do until (totaldays <= ref_days); 
set have; 

by ID ref_days notsorted;

    if first.id then totaldays=0; 
    else totaldays+lags; 
    end; 
run;
```

Required Output:

```
ID Date ref_days lags total_days
1  2017-02-02 224 . 0
1  2017-02-02 224 84 84
1  2017-02-02 224 84 168
2  2015-01-21 213 300 388 
3  2016-02-12 560 95 .
3  2016-02-12 300 86 181
3  2016-02-12 300 82 263
3  2016-02-12 300 69 .
3  2016-02-12 300 77 146
```

Comment: thank you, this is my first question so a bit messy, however I edited

Comment: I cannot understand your question. You mention _"I want to bring out  the last value close to the reference days"_. What does that mean? I don't see that happening in your "required output". Also, why does the value for `ref_days` in the required output change for `ID=3` from your starting data?

Comment: your question still is hard to understand

Comment: You can use ABS(ref_days - total_days) to get a measure of how close each observation is to your target, then sort by that value, then keep the first (closest) observation as your output.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I did similar to this via Proc sql. It calculates all the distances and takes the closest one. It works with moderate size dataset. Hopefully it is of some use.

```
proc sql;
    select * from 
    (
        select *, 
        abs(t1.link-t2.link) as dist /*In your case these would be dateVars*/
        from test1 t1
        left join test2 t2 
        on 1=1) group by system1 having dist=min(dist); 
;
quit;
```

There was some talk that the left join on 1=1 is a bit silly (as full outter join would suffice, or something.) However this worked for the problem in question.